# php: Accessing class variables in constructor

Tags: php, oop

I don't understand why the following isn't working for me. I copied what I found in some tutorials, but I get an error when running the program:

```
class tc {
    private $test = NULL;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->$test = 'sdfsdf';
    }
}
```

Creating the object:

```
$test = new tc;

Undefined variable: test
Cannot access empty property..
```

I know this is very basic, but don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try `$this->test` (as Abra pointed out). Commented before I saw it.

Comment: Also, maybe don't use those tutorials :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $this->test = 'sdfsdf';
//not
 $this->$test = 'sdfsdf';
```

Notice no `$`.

Comment: Wow. Its the end of the day and I'm tired. That's my excuse.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Maybe the problem is that he was already drinking beer? (Just kidding)